# Why did it take so long for Alia to succumb to the Other Memory of the Baron?

Tags: dune

I would have expected that she would have succumbed at an early age, not lasting into adulthood before she lost control to the others who would control her.

Comment: Because Herbert changed the universe such that the memory of male ancestors was contained in the other memory only then.

Answer (score 10):

Alia's loss of control (to the Baron) is provoked by her taking ever-increasing overdoses of spice in order to try to see her visions; of Paul's death, her own death and the subsequent reign of terror by his son, more clearly.

> He studied her a moment. Then: “You know the answer as well as I do.
> They had secure personalities by the time they came to Arrakis. The
> spice trance—well …” He shrugged. “They weren’t born into this world
> already possessed of their ancestors. Alia, though …”
>
> “Why didn’t she believe the Bene Gesserit warnings?” Ghanima chewed
> her lower lip. “Alia had the same information to draw upon that we
> do.”
>
> “They already were calling her Abomination,” Leto said. “Don’t you
> find it tempting to find out if you’re stronger than all of those …”

...

> “We must delay and delay and delay every time she urges the trance
> upon us. Extreme caution with a spice overdose; that’s our best
> course.”
>
> “An overdose would have to be pretty large,” Ghanima said.
>
> “Our tolerance is probably high,” he agreed. “Look how much Alia
> requires. ”
>
> “I pity her,” Ghanima said. **“The lure of it must’ve been subtle and
> insidious, creeping up on her until …”**
>
> **“She’s a victim, yes,” Leto said. “Abomination.”**
>
> <sub>- *Children of Dune*</sub>

Comment: While not part of the answer or the question - do you remember as to why Leto does not succumb to the Other Memory despite being forced to spice overdoses in *Children of Dune*?

Comment: @Ghanima - He does succumb, however rather than being dominated by a **singular** consciousness, he chooses to become a gestalt entity; *“I’m a **community** dominated by one who was ancient and surpassingly powerful. He fathered a dynasty which endured for three thousand of our years. His name was Harum and, until his line trailed out in the congenital weaknesses and superstitions of a descendant, his subjects lived in a rhythmic sublimity. They moved unconsciously with the changes of the seasons. They bred individuals who tended to be short-lived, superstitious, and easily led by a god-king*

Comment: You're awesome! You are probably a Mentat, very formidable indeed.